# Oracle Joining with a subquery by maximum date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, cross-join

I have a query as following below and this query has a subquery that gets the 
maximum date with a windowing function. This subquery works like a charm without the rest of the query. But with the rest of query; it doesn't return the desired result.

Problem is the result set has more than one rows (row count of CALLEXSERVICESALE times) with the same CALLID.

Query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT EC.*, CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE,
    LCESS.NAME
FROM ESASCASE EC
LEFT JOIN CALLMAIN CM
    ON (
            EC.CALLID = CM.CALLID
            OR EC.CALLID = - 1
            )
LEFT JOIN CALLDETAIL CD
    ON CM.CALLID = CD.CALLID
LEFT JOIN LOVCASETYPE LCT
    ON EC.LOVCASETYPEID = LCT.LOVCASETYPEID
LEFT JOIN LOVCASESTATUS LCS
    ON EC.LOVCASESTATUSCODE = LCS.LOVCASESTATUSCODE
INNER JOIN UNIT U
    ON EC.UNITID = U.UNITID
INNER JOIN UNIT U2
    ON U.PARENTUNITID = U2.UNITID
LEFT JOIN CALLCOURIER CC
    ON EC.REFERENCEID = CC.CALLCOURIERID
LEFT JOIN LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASON CNCL
    ON CC.LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASONID = CNCL.LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASONID
LEFT JOIN LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASON DLAY
    ON CC.LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASONID = DLAY.LOVPICKUPFAILUREREASONID
LEFT JOIN CALLEXSERVICESALE CESS
    ON CESS.CALLDETAILID = CD.CALLDETAILID
LEFT JOIN LOVCALLEXSALESTATUS LCESS
    ON LCESS.LOVCALLEXSALESTATUSID = CESS.LOVCALLEXSALESTATUSID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.CALLID,
        d.CALLDETAILID,
        d.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE
    FROM (
        SELECT CD.CALLID,
            CD.CALLDETAILID,
            CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE,
            row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY CD.CALLID ORDER BY CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE DESC
                ) seq
        FROM CALLDETAIL CD
        INNER JOIN CALLEXSERVICESALE CESS
            ON CD.CALLDETAILID = CESS.CALLDETAILID
        ) d
    WHERE d.seq = 1
    ) res
    ON CESS.CALLDETAILID = res.CALLDETAILID
        AND res.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE = CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE
LEFT JOIN WAYBILL W
    ON W.WAYBILLID = CC.WAYBILLID
WHERE CM.AUDIT_DELETED = 0
    AND EC.LOVCASETYPEID = '7'
    AND LCS.LOVCASETYPEID = '7'
    AND EC.STARTDATE >= :pDATE1
    AND EC.STARTDATE <= :pDATE2
    AND EC.AUDIT_DELETED = 0
    AND (
        :pUNITID IS NULL
        OR U.UNITID = :pUNITID
        )
    AND (
        :pPARENTUNITID IS NULL
        OR U2.UNITID = :pPARENTUNITID
        )
    AND (
        :pCUSTOMERTYPE IS NULL
        OR DECODE(CC.ACCOUNTADDRESSID, '', 'x', 'y') = :pCUSTOMERTYPE
        )
```

Current Result Set;

```
EC.*                   CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE    LCESS.NAME

EC.* (same data)       20/10/2015 15:08:50       SALE CANCELLED
EC.* (same data)       20/10/2015 09:12:30       SALE COMPLETED
```

Desired Result Set;

```
EC.*        CESS.AUDIT_CREATE_DATE    LCESS.NAME

EC.*        20/10/2015 15:08:50       SALE CANCELLED
```

where the audit_create_date is latest.

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints). One of the tips is to include a _question_. Another is to remove all of the shrubbery not pertinent to the question.

Comment: It's a shame that it's not getting the desired result. Since we don't know what this data is, nor do we know what the desired result might be, there's not much we can do here. Perhaps you could include some sample data, your desired result, or narrow the bits of the SQL down where you question lies.

Comment: T-SQL *and* Oracle? Includng the exact error message you get would be useful too.

Comment: @HABO Thank you for the tips. I've posted all query, because I am trying to understand what is wrong with the all query.

Comment: Is there a reason your join to `res` isn't using the `callid`, the partition you're using in the subquery? I'm just guessing that might be the issue though, since you haven't shown any data, current output, or expected output. You haven't clearly explained what the problem actually is.

Comment: @JNevill I tried the narrow the bits. It goes until to the subquery. Thats why I didn't understand the problem. I haven't post the result set and desired one because I have written my problem. For every ESASCASE (EC) my desired result multiplies by CALLEXSERVICESALE (CESS) and LOVCALLEXSERVICESTATUS (LCESS). But I am trying to get the latest one of CESS by AUDIT_CREATE_DATE.

Comment: @AlexPoole My join is not using the callid because it is not unique. But the calldetailid is unique. I am using callid for grouping.